# Extract fixed size and position table from pdf files in Python

Tags: python-3.x, text-extraction, pdfminer, python-camelot, excalibur-py

Say I have many similar pdf files as the one from [here](https://cw-gbl-gws-prod.azureedge.net/-/media/cw/marketbeat-pdfs/2020/q2/apac-and-gc-q2-2020/china--guangzhou--office-q2-2020-eng.pdf?rev=40dcd3dce80d48908407e5c2553016e0):

I woudld like to extract the following table and save as excel file:

[image]

I'm able to do extract table and save excel file manually with package [excalibur](https://github.com/camelot-dev/excalibur).

After installing **Excalibur** with pip3, I initialize the metadata database using:

> $ excalibur initdb

And then start the webserver using:

> $ excalibur webserver

Then go to http://localhost:5000 and start extracting tabular data from PDFs.

I wonder if it's possible to automatically do that with python script for multiple pdf files with packages such as [excalibur-py](https://pypi.org/project/excalibur-py/), [camelot](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/), [pdfminer](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six), etc, since the size and position of table are fixed for same city's reports.

You may download other report files from [this link](https://www.cushmanwakefield.com/en/insights/mb/guangzhou-marketbeat).

Many thanks at advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Camelot, you can build a pipeline like this:

```
import camelot

files_list=['FIRST_PATH','SECOND_PATH',...]
regions=['REGION_COORDINATES_1', 'REGION_COORDINATES_2',...]

for filepath in files_list:
    tables=camelot.read_pdf(filepath, pages='1-end', table_regions=regions)
    tables.export('tables.xls', f='excel')
```

*table_regions* parameter should be used when you know the approximate position of the table inside the page; if you know the exact position of the table, you should use *table_areas*.

You can read more about these parameters and other topics in the [Camelot documentation](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io).

Comment: Thanks, may I ask how could I find the table regions from pdf files?

Comment: You can use visual debugging (https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#visual-debugging). Otherwise, if you have yet extracted tables, you can get coordinates by `table._bbox`.